# Dynamically create checkbox and check if it is checked - ASP>NET

Tags: asp.net, checkbox

net so my question is, how can I check if the checkbox that I dynamically create is checked?
Here is my code for creating the checkbox:

```
TableCell cell_CheckBox = new TableCell();
CheckBox cbItemOrd = new CheckBox();
cell_CheckBox.Controls.Add(cbItemOrd);
cbList.Add(cbItemOrd);
cell_CheckBox.HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Left;
cell_CheckBox.VerticalAlign = VerticalAlign.Top;
tr.Cells.Add(cell_CheckBox);

tblSelectedCatItems.Rows.Add(tr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Give your checkbox an ID and use FindControl to retrieve it.

```
CheckBox cbItemOrd = new CheckBox();
cbItemOrd.ID="yourID";
```

You can use  cbItemOrd.Checked property to test it's state.

```
CheckBox cbItemOrd=Page.FindControl("yourID") as CheckBox;

if(cbItemOrd.Checked)
{
  ...do something
}
```

Comment: Or you can use Request.Params when PostBack is executed

Answer (score 0):

Find the control do stuff...

```
CheckBox cbItemOrd = (CheckBox) Page.FindControl(cbItemOrdId);

if(cbItemOrd.Checked)
    ...do something
```

Answer (score 0):

CheckBoxList objlst = new CheckBoxList();

//create checkbox list at run time

```
        lst.Items.Add("iteam_name");
```

// add items in that

```
        lst.Items[0].Selected == true;
```

// items is selected then it is true.